# It is said that there is no 'net' motion of charges in electrostatics. What does this 'net' motion mean?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

I read in a text book that the electric field on the surface of a conductor must always be perpendicular to the surface or else charges will have net motion. If the field is normal to the surface, will charges always be at rest?

Comment: That is the very definition of "electrostatics" ... charges are static (at rest).

Answer (score 0):

If the field lines are not normal, a component of the force by virtue of the field along the surface will be non zero and thus, cause it to accelerate, causing motion. But, will it always be at rest? Yes, there is no effect of a normal field on a stationary charge and it will not move if at rest.

Well, if you consider an ideal example where in the charge is fixed to move in a plane with electric field acting normal to the plane, the motion will not be affected. 
Now, moving charges produce magnetic field, which can then produce electric field due to change in flux and the net electric field will influence its motion.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the above figure it is clearly understood that if the net electric field has a component in the tangential direction then there would be no electrostatic equilibrium because charges would start accelerating.

Comment: If a particle has no acceleration, then it does not mean that it is necessarily at rest.

Comment: @Physics std In electrostatic equilibrium the charges at the surface of conductor are at rest